# Locating error in vector ctor from exercise in TC++PL book

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I've been working on all the exercises in Bjarne Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language' book.
I've come to one particular exercise **(E.8.4)** that has me stumped. 
This is the appendix that discusses exception safety in standard library classes. He illustrates one possible implementation of a vector's constructor and then asks the reader to find the error. The hint indicates that it has something to do with the destructor (a double free somehow maybe?) but I'm just not seeing what he's after.

From what I can tell, the allocator could throw bad_alloc, terminating the ctor. Similarly, a copy ctor on T could throw inside uninitialized_fill, which would destruct any previously copied elements and terminate the ctor. If there's an error in there, it's not obvious to me.

The exercise is worded as follows: "Find the error in the 'messy' version of vector's constructor **(E.3.1)** and write a program to get it to crash. Hint: **First implement vector's destructor.**

This is only a 1 point exercise, so I must be missing something stupidly obvious. I assume it has nothing to do with destructors throwing, as all bets are off in that case. Maybe there's an issue maintaining an invariant with the "space" and "last" fields?

I'd love to hear anyone's ideas.

Here is the associated code:

```
template<class T, class A = std::allocator<T> >
class vector {
private:
    T* v;
    T* space;
    T* last;
    A alloc;

    void destroy_all();
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;

    explicit vector(size_type n, const T& val = T(), const A& = A());
    vector(const vector& a);
    vector& operator=(const vector& a);
    ~vector() { destroy_all(); alloc.deallocate(v, last-v); }
    size_type size() const { return space-v; }
    size_type capacity() const { return last-v; }
    void push_back(const T&);
};

template<class T, class A>
void vector<T,A>::destroy_all() {
    for(T* p = v; p != last; p++)
        alloc.destroy(p);
}

template<class T, class A>
vector<T,A>::vector(size_type n, const T& val, const A& a) : alloc(a) {
    v = alloc.allocate(n);
    try {
        std::uninitialized_fill(v, v + n, val);
        space = last = v + n;
    }
    catch(...) {
        alloc.deallocate(v, n);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, in the case of an exception in the ctor, any previously-initialized fields are destroyed properly, but in this case that just refers to the memory holding the three T* fields and alloc, not the backing storage itself. That would have to be explicitly freed via alloc.deallocate(). While this does happen in the destructor, it's not called if the ctor is terminated by an exception.

Comment: `destroy_all()` should iterate backward, not forward, but that's not within the constructor.

Comment: Good point, thanks. (Note, that part was added by me - so my fault!)

Comment: Maybe it's because the constructor doesn't use `A::construct`?  Though I'm not sure a custom allocator is allowed to vary much from just calling placement new.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the constructor for `T` can throw, meaning that this can throw:

```
std::uninitialized_fill(v, v + n, val);
```

When that happens, the `catch(...)` clause deallocates memory without properly destroying any `T` objects that may have been already constructed.

Comment: I also thought this may be the problem, but according to Bjarne, uninitialized_fill() will destruct any elements it allocated if an exception is thrown in a constructor. I've also verified that this is the case on my standard library implementation.

Comment: @BrettErnst Nice research.  I'll pass then, and leave this up so you don't get the same answer again.

Answer (score 0):

[`allocator::allocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) can throw `std::bad_alloc`. In that case you have uninitialized `v` and even if you recover from insufficient memory, you will segfault on destruction.

Another problem is with [`std::initialized_fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill). If it throws, you free the internal storage without marking the data pointer as invalid. The destructor will free the same memory again.